# MySQL join between two columns with case condition

Tags: mysql

i have an table with data which has both category and subcategory data in it.

**So what is category and sub-category?** category is the parent and sub-category is the child. Both data is similar except for one difference, parent_id for sub_category is id of the category.

Sample Data:
[image: sample data]

**What is required?**

sub-category name in the result should be **category-name +'-'+ sub-category-name**

Sample Result:
[image: Sample Result]

**What is my attempt to solve the problem?**

MySQL query which i have returning is done only to extract the sub-category only with the names:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(wcfc1.feed_category_name,
            '-',
            wcfc2.feed_category_name) AS feed_category_name,
    wcfc2.feed_category_id,
    wcfc2.parent_id,
    wcfc2.category_type_id
FROM
    wc_feed_categories wcfc1
        JOIN
    wc_feed_categories wcfc2 ON wcfc1.feed_category_id = wcfc2.parent_id;
```

This query is showing only:
[image: MyResult]

i'm not able to figure out, how to write a query to show both category and sub-category with the name change in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    JOIN
wc_feed_categories wcfc2 ON wcfc1.feed_category_id = wcfc2.parent_id;
```

try

```
    LEFT JOIN
wc_feed_categories wcfc2 ON wcfc1.parent_id = wcfc2.feed_category_id;
```

so your query will be:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN wcfc1.parent_id = 0 THEN wcfc1.feed_category_name
       ELSE
            CONCAT(wcfc2.feed_category_name,  -- parent category
               '-', 
               wcfc1.feed_category_name)      -- child category
       END AS feed_category_name,
    wcfc1.feed_category_id,
    wcfc1.parent_id
FROM
    wc_feed_categories wcfc1
        LEFT JOIN
    wc_feed_categories wcfc2 ON wcfc1.parent_id = wcfc2.feed_category_id;
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1be49/6)

Comment: it works and i have understood how it is executing.